# Galaxy s5 bricked

Tags: adb, samsung, stock-android, fastboot

I have a galaxy s5 that goes in bootloop.It doesn't enter in recovery but it goes in download mode.I have available an other s5.Is there something to do to make possible that the galaxy cone to work again?

Comment: Use the Heimdall Suite to flash a recovery image.

Answer (score 0):

If you own windows, use the lastest version of Odin. Then look for your STOCK rom on the internet and then download it. THEN, follow the steps here:   http://www.w0lfdroid.com/2014/04/How-to-Flash-Restore-Galaxy-S5-All-Variants-to-Stock-ROM-Using-Odin3.html

Comment: I have already done this...nothing:(:(:(

Comment: Can you please give me some info about your phone? Do you remember what model? What carrier?